# Python stripping words upon specific condition in a list of sentences

Tags: python, string

My starting file was .txt one, that looked like:

```
https://www.website.com/something1/id=39494 notes !!!! other notes
https://www.website2.com/something1/id=596774 ... notes2 !! other notes2
```

and so on.. so very messy

to clean it up I did:

```
import re

with open('file.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    places = [current_place.rstrip() for current_place in filehandle.readlines()]

filtered = [x for x in places if x.strip()]
```

This gave me a list of websites (without spaces in between) but still with notes in the same string.

My goal is the first have a list of "cleaned" websites without any notes afterwords:

```
https://www.website.com/something1/id=39494 
https://www.website2.com/something1/id=596774
```

For that I thought to target the space after the end of website and get rid of all the words afterwords:

```
for s in filtered:
    f = re.search('\s')
```

This returns an error, but even if it worked it wouldn't return what I thought.

The second step is to strip the website of some characters and compose it like: https://www.website.com/embed/id=39494

but this would come later.

I just wonder how can I achieve the first step and get rid of the notes after the website and have a clean list.

Comment: Try `with open('file.txt', 'r') as f: for line in f: if line.strip().startswith('http'): print(line.strip().split()[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each line consists of a URL followed by a space and any other text, you can simply split by the space and take the first element of each line:

```
urls = []
with open('file.txt') as filehandle:
  for line in filehandle:
    if not line.strip(): continue # skip empty lines
    urls.append(line.split(" ")[0])

# now the variable `urls` should contain all the URLs you are looking for
```

EDIT: second step

```
for url in urls:
  print('<iframe src="{}"></iframe>'.format(url))
```

Comment: Note that I passed in a string with a space into `split()` but you can also omit that since that's the default parameter anyways. I added it to be more explicit

Comment: thanks, also for the second step! I noticed the <iframe> addition is in print(), could have been possible to have it stably written in a list?

Comment: @Steven of course, you can also write the HTML into a list, one long string or a file. In all those cases you would take the argument of `print()` and use a list appending function, string concatenation or file writing function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
# to read the lines
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    strlist = f.readlines()
# list to store the URLs
webs = []
for x in strlist:
    webs.append(x.split(' ')[0])
print(webs)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case if the URL position is not always at the beginning of the line. You can try

```
https?:\/\/www\.\w+\.com\/\w+\/id=(\d+)
```

then you can use back reference to get the URL and id.

Code example

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
for line in file:
    m = re.match(r'https?:\/\/www\.\w+\.com\/\w+\/id=(\d+)', line)
    if m:
        print("URL=%s" % m.group(0))
        print("ID=%d" % int(m.group(1)))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/FeSHcc/1)